# .NET Treeview NodeMouseClick Event has lag?

Tags: c#, events, treeview, lag

I have this code:

```
private void treeView1_NodeMouseClick(object sender, TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e)
        {
            if (treeView1.SelectedNode.Nodes.Count == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("The node does not have any children.");
            }
        }
```

When a treeView node which has no children is clicked, there seems to be a lag on the event firing.

For example:

1. I click on a parent node with children - MessageBox does not fire
2. I click on a child node without children - MessageBox does not fire
3. I click on a child node without children again - Messagebox fires
4. I click on a parent node with children - Messagebox fires
5. I click on a parent node with children again - messagebox does not fire.

During debug, the `SelectedNode.Count` value seems to be the number from the click before it.

What is going on here?

Comment: [TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs.Node Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.treenodemouseclickeventargs.node).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem stems from the fact that the `OnNodeMouseClick` is fired before any selection-related events (`OnBeforeSelect` & `OnAfterSelect`) which means the `SelectedNode` you're inspecting has not been updated yet.

If you only care about the *selection changing*, then subscribe to [`BeforeSelect`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.treeview.beforeselect) (with the ability to cancel the selection) or [`AfterSelect`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.treeview.afterselect) instead. This will handle changing selections using the keyboard as well.

Unlike the selection-related events, `NodeMouseClick` will still trigger even if the the selected node is *not changing* (e.g. you're clicking on an already-selected node). Also, as the name implies, this only works on *mouse click* and *not when using the keyboard* to navigate your tree.

To see what is actually happening in the background, you can have a look at the source code for TreeView, specifically the [WmNotify method](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/TreeView.cs,35e9972affaafacd). You'll see that `NodeMouseClick` is triggered by a windows `NM_CLICK` message. It then performs a Hit Test at the clicked (x,y) coordinate to look for a node under the mouse, and if found, give it back to you inside the [`TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.treenodemouseclickeventargs) argument of the event.

TLDR: When subscribing to `NodeMouseClick`, your selection hasn't changed yet (and it might not be changing), but you can see the clicked node by inspecting the event arg. Only works when using mouse, not keyboard.

Comment: Perfect - this worked like a charm. I figured it was something I was missing. thanks for the input.